# Why Alexa custom slot value cannot recognize 'echo xxx'?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to build a Amazon Alexa skill using a custom slot. While it works well if I set the custom slot value as 'kind people', or something else, it cannot recognize my input if I use 'echo dot'. What is the limitation for Alexa custom slot value? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [offical documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/create-and-edit-custom-slot-types.html) says only this about the limitation on custom slot values:

> The set of custom values can be anything supported by your skill's
>   handling of the slot as long as it can be spoken by a user, although
>   words not found in a typical dictionary for the skill's language may
>   not be recognized.

Link also mentions a useful tip for debugging

> **Tip**: When a user's utterance resolves to a slot that uses a custom
>   slot type, the IntentRequest includes a resolutions object that
>   represents the results of entity resolution. You can check the value
>   of resolutionsPerAuthority[].status.code to determine whether the
>   value provided by the user matches a slot type value or synonym you
>   have defined. You can also define IDs for particular slot values to
>   simplify handling them in your code. See Define Synonyms and IDs for
>   Slot Type Values (Entity Resolution).

Here is the documentation link : https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/create-and-edit-custom-slot-types.html

Comment: Thanks, Ahsan! But I feel 'echo dot' can be found in a typical dictionary. I guess the root cause is due to word 'echo'. 'echo' seems a sensitive word as we can also say 'echo [some word]' to Alexa, and then Alexa will repeat the [some word]. I found 'echo dot' can be recognized correctly if we put it in the middle of a sentence. So finally I changed my utterance to be '[some words] of echo dot' as a work around.